# Shell script for daily disk usage report

Tags: scripting, disk-space-utilization

I am doing backups on my local drives. The drives are mounted in /media folder.
Now I want to run a cron job daily which will tell me, in a table format, how much disk is used by certain folders and how much free space is left on the drive.

It would be good if I can insert that info into a database and I can see that info via a webpage on locahost.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner will list the top-level directories from the directory it is executed in, and print their sizes sorted in MB. You can tweak it for your tastes.

`for d in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d); do du -sm $d; done | sort -nk 1`

Simple tweaks,

1. `find /dir/path` -- will do this for a specified directory
2. `du` can be used in other forms, this one is doing a summary in MB
3. If your directories have the space characters, you can precede with,
   (as further cleaned-up by `Dennis`; thanks for that tip)
   `IFS=$'\n';`
   <sup>I am somehow used to exact filters rather than globbing; Dennis has more ideas</sup>
4. You can use `sort -nrk 1` to sort the output in descending order of size
5. I missed adding `-mindepth 1` there,
   When you add that, it will skip showing the base-directory (`/dir/path` etc) size in the results

Some other answer here will probably give you a good handle on storing this into databases and displaying on web-pages. I would have just converted it to CSV files and listed summaries with a file path in the browser (but, that may not be too optimal for storage and view with lots of data over time).

<sup>[meta, editing query: the fourth item shows up as `4` in the preview when I edit this answer,

but says `1` in the real-view. Anyone know what I am missing in this markdown?;

This got fixed when I removed the newlines in point-3,

you'll need to look at the earlier revision to see what I mean here...]</sup>

---

Update with basics (based on your comment):

1. Look at [**using the terminal**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) for command-line processing with Ubuntu
2. Once you have the terminal started,
   Change to a directory of interest (try some sample directory),
   (maybe your firefox profile for example -- `cd ./mozilla`)
   <sup>and, don't try too many things in that directory, you could break your browser.</sup>
3. Now copy the first for-loop line as-is from above and paste it on the command prompt in that terminal
4. press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
5. look at the output
6. Another reference to get more on how to use the command-line for 'scripting',
   [**Bash Shell Tutorials**](https://superuser.com/questions/25486/bash-shell-tutorials) at Superuser

Tell us which level of detail you want from there.

Comment: If you want to set IFS to a newline, this is more readable: `IFS=$'\n'`, but I would use globbing: `for d in */; do ...` and if you want to accommodate spaces, it's essential that you quote your variable: `... du -sm "$d" ...`

Comment: sorry for being dumb but i really don't know what u guys are talking about

Answer (score 1):

If you want the space on partitions as a table, you can simply call

```
df -h | column -t
```

Add this to a crontab with your email address.df -h | column -t

Comment: -bash: column: command not found. => Could you please elaborate on how to make your command work, or what the prerequisites are ?

Answer (score 0):

for nice columnar output, use the POSIX output format so as to avoid restricted space when you are using remote sessions using pts/?

df -hP | column -t